# Putting a bar in the margin

Tags: margins, rules

I sometimes want to give examples in a document I am writing. Because these examples are quite general it could be difficult for readers to see the difference between the examples and the theoretical analysis. Therefore I want to put a long vertical bar (that spans the entire example) in the margin indicating the text next to it is an example. It could be that the example uses two pages or more.

Is there any helpful package to do this. An environment would be fine. Something like this:

```
\begin{example}
...
\end{example}
```

Other suggestions to indicate the difference are welcome too. First I thought using a different background color. But I want to keep the document printable in Black/White and reading text with a gray background isn't that easy. A horizontal line at the begin and end is also an option but after two pages people could get confused.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [`framed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/framed) package provides a `leftbar` environment that does something like what you want:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{framed,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{leftbar}
This is a test.
\end{leftbar}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you edit this answer to include a little explanation. Ideally, answers shouldn't just be a code snippet. All you need to do is say something like "The [`framed`](http://ctan.org/pkg/framed) package provides a `leftbar` environment that does something like what you want"

Answer (score 16):

Have a look at `changebar` package: https://ctan.org/pkg/changebar

An example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[color]{changebar}
\cbcolor{blue}
\usepackage{lipsum}% for random text only
\begin{document}

\cbstart
\lipsum[1]
\cbend

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15):

You can also use PDF annotations with the [pdfcomment](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcomment) package

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[svgnames,rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage[subject={Top1},author={Josef}]{pdfcomment}
\begin{document}
\begin{pdfsidelinecomment}[color=red,icolor=yellow,caption=inline,linebegin={/Butt},lineend={/Square},linewidth=2bp,linesep=1cm]{Example}
\lipsum[2]
\end{pdfsidelinecomment}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Will these work in all PDF readers and will the appear when the document is printed?

Comment: @doncherry 1. They will work in every PDF reader, which fully implements the PDF spec ;-)  No, that's not just Adobe Reader, although that might be the Linux perspective. 2. For printing you have to allow printing annotations in the Prefernces (AR) and in the print dialog.  There's a section in the documentation of `pdfcomment`

Comment: The link of the `pdfcomment` package is dead. Please consider updating it.

Answer (score 5):

[`mdframed`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) provides a flexible way of adding a (partial) frame around a block of content:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed,lipsum}
\newmdenv[
  leftmargin = 0pt,
  innerleftmargin = 1em,
  innertopmargin = 0pt,
  innerbottommargin = 0pt,
  innerrightmargin = 0pt,
  rightmargin = 0pt,
  linewidth = 3pt,
  topline = false,
  rightline = false,
  bottomline = false
  ]{leftbar}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{leftbar}
\lipsum[2]
\end{leftbar}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

The above output is similar to what is achieved using the [`leftbar` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/leftbar).

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility for indicating an example:
If your document has anything to do with code, you might want to consider use of `\verb` and the `verbatim` environment.  All it does is place the example in monospaced font, and it's wysiwyg.  So you can also type up LaTeX examples as-is.  I use the `\verb` command for short, in-line examples, and the `verbatim` environment for longer ones like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

This is the explanation for the \verb#lambda# function:
\begin{verbatim}
>>> #this is a comment 
...
>>> sq = lambda x: x**2
>>> sq(2)
\end{verbatim}
will return \verb#4#.

\end{document}
```

produces this:

[image]

Note you don't have to use `##` to delimit the `\verb` command, you can use another pair, like `!!`.

Comment: Is this an answer to another question? I fail to see the relation to the OP.

Comment: @Hendrik: He also asked for other suggestions to indicate examples.  If his examples are of code, that could be one way to do it, no?

Comment: I'd explain that your suggestion is to use a different font "to indicate the difference". After all, _this_ is the part of the question you're addressing, and I honestly didn't get it.

Answer (score 3):

Another option comes from [the package `thmbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/thmbox), which provide a `leftbar` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{thmbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{leftbar}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{leftbar}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]