# Why does the `&` reset grouping?

Tags: align, grouping, ampersand

In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23007/changbars-to-indicate-location-of-conditional-text/23159#23159), I used `\tikzmark` to mark the extent of a typeset piece of text, so I could draw changebars next to it.  But it initially seemed that the changebars "disappear" with math-mode content.  After some debugging, I whittled it down to the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newlength\aLength
\newcommand{\tester}[1]{%
  \setlength{\aLength}{50pt}%
  \def\aMacro{Hello}%
  \typeout{Before: \the\aLength, and \aMacro}%
  #1%
  \typeout{After: \the\aLength, and \ifdef{\aMacro}{\aMacro}{undefined!!}}
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \tester{0}
  \tester{ 0 & 1 }
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

This yields the following behavior:

```
Before: 50.0pt, and Hello
After: 50.0pt, and Hello
Before: 50.0pt, and Hello
After: 0.0pt, and undefined!!
Before: 50.0pt, and Hello
After: 50.0pt, and Hello
Before: 50.0pt, and Hello
After: 0.0pt, and undefined!!
```

I have two questions on this output:

1. Why are there four sets of output?  The MWE calls `\tester` only twice.
2. What exactly is `&` doing to cause `\aLength` and `\aMacro` to revert to their previous values?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`align` builds an alignment similar in essence to a `tabular`; each cell forms a group and there's not much to do about this except to perform global assignments:

```
\global\aLength=50pt\relax
```

Moreover, `align` reads its contents twice: the first time to measure the columns and the second time to do the actual typesetting.

The conditional it uses to see if it's on the first step is `\ifmeasuring@`; so

```
\ifmeasuring@\typeout{...}\fi
```

will show the message only once. You have to choose whether doing the (global) assignments during both steps or only once. Pay attention to the `@` in the name.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid it was something like that.  Any thoughts on question part #1?

Comment: Here's the explanation