# To clearly separate block inside a chapter

Tags: block

I get many times things that are somehow related to the main topic and should be separated by blue background, for instance.

I do at the moment only

```
\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{question}[theorem]{Question}
\begin{document}
\begin{question}
Lorem ipsum?
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

I get like this

[image]

where the question -environment only adds the question mark to the front.
I think there is some problem because the environment should be numbered, first of all.

**How can you make distinguish the question environment better?**

Comment: Related Question: [Environments for visually setting text apart](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37245/environments-for-visually-setting-text-apart).

Comment: Do you want the structure to be numbered?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways, and it all depends on the desired final layout. Below, two options: one using the standard `quote` environment; the other one using [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newmdenv[linecolor=cyan,backgroundcolor=cyan!20]{question}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{quote}
\lipsum[2]
\end{quote}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{question}
\lipsum[2]
\end{question}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

And with [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{most}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{question}{breakable,colframe=cyan,colback=cyan!20}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{question}
\lipsum[2]
\end{question}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option using a list through [`changepage`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/changepage):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{question}
  {\par\smallskip\begin{adjustwidth}{1em}{1em}\small\itshape}
  {\end{adjustwidth}\par\smallskip}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{question}
\lipsum[2]
\end{question}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The options using `mdframed` and `tcolorbox` offer you many customization possibilities; please refer to the documentation of the packages.

For example, you can define your structure as a theorem-like block using, for example, `amsthm` and then surround it with a mdframed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheorem{question}{Question}
\mdfdefinestyle{que}{
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=cyan!20,
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=que]{question}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{question}
\lipsum[2]
\end{question}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

A numbered structure with `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]
  {question}
  {colback=cyan!20,colframe=cyan,fonttitle=\bfseries,
  title=Question~\thetcbcounter}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{question}
\lipsum[2]
\end{question}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear answer! I like most the last proposal with mdframed and tcolor box because of cusmotisation possibilities.

Comment: I like your update now most (the last option with numbered structure). :)

Comment: Do you need to add some specific number, like [1], in the command? I get these errors https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62073194/Screen%20Shot%202014-02-20%20at%2022.01.33.png May be complications of my other commands.

Comment: @Masi No, no need to add anything else in my examples; looking at the error messages, it seems that you are using an old version of `tcolorbox`. I am using version 2.70 (2014/02/06).

Comment: I put this "\listfiles" to my preamble, but I did not find log file in the same directory (not sure where it goes). I am using the newest OSX with MacTex. My installation is from 2013.

Comment: @Masi The list of files and versions goes to the .log file (which should be in the same directory as the .tex), but italso gets output to the console. Notice that eventhough your installation is from 2013, the tcolorbox has suffered several updates (the version I use is a few days old only).

Comment: @Masi If you still experience problems, let me know and I can give you a similar version but with `mdframed`.

Comment: I tried the second to last with mdframed. The numbering does not work for some reason: I see like this https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62073194/Screen%20Shot%202014-02-21%20at%2017.59.48.png **How can you set the numbering?** It can be a bug with my versions of the software.

Comment: @Masi can you post elsewhere the code you used with `mdframed`? Just a simple document (like the ones in my answers) showing only the relevant settings and allowing me to reproduce the undesired bahaviour?

Comment: **Extension to Gonzalo's answer.** The bug of missing numbering (marked by question marks) was because of this line \usepackage{unicode-math} % This causes bugs tbox environment

Comment: I managed to find the bug which caused the question marks. I used the braces with tkiz in some part of my code. It requires the package **unicode-math**. I just removed unicode-math. **Can you use tkiz with braces without unicode-math package?**

Comment: @Masi I don't understand your question. What do you mean by "use tkiz with braces"? Please consider opening a follow-up question.

Comment: @ I added the package to the body of the question because I used it for the screenshot.

Comment: @Masi please, don't do that. The original question had nothing to do with this. As I said, consider opening a new question and please roll-back the edit; otherwise, it might be confusing for someone reading the question.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I opened a new question here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161809/why-unicode-math-not-working-with-tikz