# How to have upside down text in body?

Tags: fonts, rotating, block

I have environments Question (described in [To clearly separate block inside a chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161528/to-clearly-separate-block-inside-a-chapter)) and Answer blocks.
I want the Answer block be the same as as Question block but the text upside down in it.

Minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}
\mdfdefinestyle{que}{
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=cyan!20,
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=que]{question}

\newtheorem{answer}{Answer}
\mdfdefinestyle{ans}{
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=yellow!20
  % , rotatebox
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=ans]{answer}


\begin{document}
\begin{question}
\textbf{E.coli.}
Escherichia coli ...
\end{question}
\begin{answer}
Lorem
\end{answer}
\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

**How can you have upside down text in the Answer environment?**
I want that the text is difficult to read so the readers try to answer the question themselves before looking for the answer.
Any other way to include answers is also accepted, since I am not sure which is the best way to do it.
I however want personally that those answer are visible in the draw code just after the question.

Comment: you could use `\rotatebox`

Comment: In the linked answer which is the answer part? The one inside block? Which is the question?

Comment: I suggest you to add clarification: as it stands, to me is not clear at all what _How can you have upside down text in such environment?_ does mean.

Comment: Thank you for the comments! I finally got the minimal thing done.

Comment: Did you have a look at the top-voted questions in the [tag:rotating] tag?

Comment: You don't need to load the `mdframed` package twice.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

See the last edit for automatic toggling

You can define a new environment `Answer` based on your `answer` environment:

```
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{Answer}
{%
\noindent
\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{%
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
\begin{answer}
\BODY
\end{answer}%
\end{minipage}%
}%
}%
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}
\mdfdefinestyle{que}{
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=cyan!20,
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=que]{question}

\newtheorem{answer}{Answer}
\mdfdefinestyle{ans}{
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=yellow!20
  % , rotatebox
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=ans]{answer}

\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{Answer}
{%
\noindent
\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{%
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
\begin{answer}
\BODY
\end{answer}%
\end{minipage}%
}%
}%


\begin{document}
\begin{question}
\textbf{E.coli.}
Escherichia coli ...
\end{question}
\begin{Answer}
Lorem ipsum is not an answer to this question but this text will provide some dummy answer for two lines all together.
\end{Answer}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Making it to difficult to read?. Here we go:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}
\mdfdefinestyle{que}{
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=cyan!20,
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=que]{question}

\newtheorem{answer}{Answer}
\mdfdefinestyle{ans}{
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=yellow!20
  % , rotatebox
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=ans]{answer}

\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{Answer}
{%
\noindent
\reflectbox{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{%
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
\begin{answer}
\BODY
\end{answer}%
\end{minipage}%
}%
}}%


\begin{document}
\begin{question}
\textbf{E.coli.}
Escherichia coli ...
\end{question}
\begin{Answer}
Lorem ipsum is not an answer to this question but this text will provide some dummy answer for two lines all together.
\end{Answer}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With

```
\NewEnviron{Answer}
{%
\noindent
\scalebox{1}[-1]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{%
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
\begin{answer}
\BODY
\end{answer}%
\end{minipage}%
}%
}}%
```

one gets

[image]

but beware of those who bring mirrors ;)

In fact, with `\scalebox` alone, the former orientations can be achieved without using `\rotatebox`.

## Last edit:

If you want to automatically show/hide answers here is a way.  See the commented code lines

```
%\setboolean{answers}{true}  %%% uncomment to show answers properly
\setboolean{answers}{false}  %%% comment to show answers properly
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}
\mdfdefinestyle{que}{
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=cyan!20,
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=que]{question}

\newtheorem{answer}{Answer}
\mdfdefinestyle{ans}{
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=yellow!20
  % , rotatebox
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=ans]{answer}

\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{answers}
%\setboolean{answers}{true}  %%% uncomment to show answers properly
\setboolean{answers}{false}  %%% comment to show answers properly


\ifthenelse{\boolean{answers}}%
  {%
  \NewEnviron{Answer}
    {%
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
        \begin{answer}
            \BODY
        \end{answer}%
    \end{minipage}%  here put what the command has to do when outside
        }%
}%
    {\NewEnviron{Answer}
    {%
    \noindent
    \scalebox{1}[-1]{%
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
        \begin{answer}
            \BODY
        \end{answer}%
    \end{minipage}%
       }%
    }%
}%


\begin{document}
\begin{question}
\textbf{E.coli.}
Escherichia coli ...
\end{question}
\begin{Answer}
Lorem ipsum is not an answer to this question but this text will provide some dummy answer for two lines all together.
\end{Answer}
\end{document}
```

With

```
\setboolean{answers}{false}
```

we get:

[image]

With

```
\setboolean{answers}{true}
```

we get:

[image]

**With optional argument**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}
\mdfdefinestyle{que}{
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=cyan!20,
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=que]{question}

\newtheorem{answer}{Answer}
\mdfdefinestyle{ans}{
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=yellow!20
  % , rotatebox
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=ans]{answer}

\usepackage{environ}

\def\invert{-1}
 \NewEnviron{Answer}[1][1]%
    {%
    \noindent
    \scalebox{1}[#1]{%
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}%
        \begin{answer}
            \BODY
        \end{answer}%
    \end{minipage}%
       }%
    }%

\begin{document}
\begin{question}
\textbf{E.coli.}
Escherichia coli ...
\end{question}
\begin{Answer}
Lorem ipsum is not an answer to this question but this text will provide some dummy answer for two lines all together.
\end{Answer}

\begin{question}
\textbf{E.coli.}
Escherichia coli ...
\end{question}
\begin{Answer}[\invert] 
Lorem ipsum is not an answer to this question but this text will provide some dummy answer for two lines all together.
\end{Answer}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why loading `mdframed` twice?

Comment: **What is the benefit of using the minipage here, instead of   tikzpicture -environment, described in Gonzalo's answer?**

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thank you. As usual remnant. Corrected :)

Comment: @Masi: `minipage` will allow breaking the lines, otherwise rotatebox will not.

Comment: @Masi: Though your question in comment is good: What is the benefit of making it bold? (In other words: Let it be, this is not necessary, some people feel even upset with such things.)

Comment: @HarishKumar I just noticed that I need this kind of inverting text upside down and back in different parts of by document. So the command should be so simple as $\begin{answer}[invert]...$ and normal answer $\begin{answer}...$. Is there any way to use such a syntax?

Comment: @Masi See the edit at the end. It may need some polishing. But now I gotta go. :)

Answer (score 25):

One idea is to define a new environment which places the answer contents inside a TikZ `\node` and rotates it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheorem{question}{Question}
\mdfdefinestyle{que}{
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=cyan!20,
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=que]{question}

\newtheorem{answer}{Answer}
\mdfdefinestyle{ans}{
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=yellow!20
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=ans]{answer}

\NewEnviron{rotanswer}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[rotate=180,inner sep=0pt] {\parbox{\linewidth}{%
  \begin{answer}
  \BODY
  \end{answer}}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
\textbf{E.coli.}
Escherichia coli ...
\end{question}
\begin{rotanswer}
Lorem
\end{rotanswer}

\begin{question}
\textbf{E.coli.}
Escherichia coli ...
\end{question}
\begin{rotanswer}
\lipsum[4]
\end{rotanswer}

\end{document}
```

[image]

you can make things even harder for someone who decides to read the answer ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheorem{question}{Question}
\mdfdefinestyle{que}{
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=cyan!20,
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=que]{question}

\newtheorem{answer}{Answer}
\mdfdefinestyle{ans}{
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=yellow!20
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=ans]{answer}

\NewEnviron{rotanswer}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[rotate=180,inner sep=0pt,xscale=-1] {\parbox{\linewidth}{%
  \begin{answer}
  \BODY
  \end{answer}}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
\textbf{E.coli.}
Escherichia coli ...
\end{question}
\begin{rotanswer}
Lorem
\end{rotanswer}

\begin{question}
\textbf{E.coli.}
Escherichia coli ...
\end{question}
\begin{rotanswer}
\lipsum[4]
\end{rotanswer}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I ask your opinion about the answer which I accepted above because I think least packages used is the best way to go so code keeps simple. I know you understand this topic better than me. What are the possible drawbacks without the Environ package?

Comment: @Masi No drawbacks; the answer you accepted also does what you need. The only advantage of my answer compared to the others is that with TikZ, you can also apply some other effects (opacity, etc.) but if no such effects are desired, then any of the other answers is perfectly valid and does what you required, And you're right, if no "special effects" are needed, the accepted answer has economy in the use of packages.

Comment: I just noticed that I need the backgrounds with text Draft in some of my documents: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162026/to-include-big-draft-text-as-background It may come a day when your answer is best one soon again.

Answer (score 12):

Here's another solution that doesn't need the `environ` package because it uses a `newsavebox` instead.

The different part compared to the other answers is

```
\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\@my@box}
\newenvironment{Answer}%
{%
    \noindent
    \begin{lrbox}{\@my@box}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    \begin{answer}
}%
{%
    \end{answer}%
    \end{minipage}%
    \end{lrbox}%
    \rotatebox{180}{\usebox{\@my@box}}
}%
```

which, as you can see, stores the content of the environment in `\@my@box` and then rotates it using `rotatebox` from the [`graphicx`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/graphicx) package, which is automatically loaded by [`mdframed`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/mdframed)  and [`tikz`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tikz).

The output is the same as in the other answers.

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}
\mdfdefinestyle{que}{
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=cyan!20,
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=que]{question}

\newtheorem{answer}{Answer}
\mdfdefinestyle{ans}{
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=yellow!20
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=ans]{answer}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\@my@box}
\newenvironment{Answer}%
{%
    \noindent
    \begin{lrbox}{\@my@box}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    \begin{answer}
}%
{%
    \end{answer}%
    \end{minipage}%
    \end{lrbox}%
    \rotatebox{180}{\usebox{\@my@box}}
}%


\begin{document}
\begin{question}
\textbf{E.coli.}
Escherichia coli ...
\end{question}
\begin{Answer}
Lorem ipsum is not an answer to this question but this text will provide some dummy answer for two lines all together.
\end{Answer}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why a command with @? Should also work without.

Comment: Have you run your command? I cannot get rotation of the answer by this method although I run it exactly as you have it here.

Comment: @Masi I always test my answers :) I just copied it into a new file and ran it again- works fine. Is your distribution up to date?

Comment: The problem was that you use the word "[A]nswer", while I used the word "answer" and "answers_original" so "\newenvironment{answer}...\begin{answer_original}...\end{answer_original}". I was confused by your notation. Thank you for simpler answer!