# How to include Big Draft text as background only for imported document part

Tags: backgrounds, import

I want to include a big "Draft" text on the background in some files imported by 
the `import` package in this way:

```
\subimport{}{test.text}
```

How can you include such a big "Draft" text to the background of some imported files?. This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]  % main dummy text  
\newpage
\subimport{}{test.tex} % subdocument that must have the a big "Draft" in the background 
\end{document}
```

The `test.tex` file is:

```
\lipsum[1-10]
```

Comment: After read twice, I guess that the question is simply insert  "Draft" in the background of only the imported pages with the `import` package. Added a MWE and vote to reopen.

Comment: @Masi, Use the package `background` and insert  some like `\backgroundsetup{contents=Draft,color=blue!30}` before of `\subimport` and `\backgroundsetup{contents={}}` for parts with normal text.

Comment: @Fran I honestly have no idea how you managed to understand that from the original question. I salute you for your edit, but it may just be a shot in the dark. In any case, no offense, but I don't think the OP's behaviour (cryptic question, little research, no MWE, etc.) should be encouraged...

Comment: @Jubbobs You're right. Clairvoyance is a risky job when you're wrong and even when you hit. `:-)` But the alternative was to leave it closed and punish the entire community, when I was convinced that I knew the answer. A closed question as unclear only is useful to waste time if you find it. Moreover, I think sometimes it's good to lead by example. Otherwise, it would not make sense the edit button in the questions of others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`background`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package; using  `\backgroundsetup{contents={}}` you remove the background material for the "normal text" pages and with `\backgroundsetup{contents={Draft}}` you activate the material for the included pages (`\newpage`, or better yet, `\clearpage` must be used before changing the material):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
\begin{document}
\backgroundsetup{contents={}}
\lipsum[1-5]  % main dummy text  
\clearpage
\backgroundsetup{contents={Draft}}
\subimport{}{test.tex} % subdocument that must have the a big "Draft" in the background
\clearpage 
\backgroundsetup{contents={}}
\newpage
\lipsum[1-5]  % main dummy text  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, using the key-value interface, you can change the color, position, opacity of the "Draft" string.

Comment: As addition: Some other possible packages without trying to be complete: [`draftmark`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/draftmark) and its much more powerful (but also complex) successor [`xwatermark`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xwatermark).

Comment: @Speravir For information, I tried to use `xwatermark` in the past to get a semi-transparent watermark *on top* of my content, but it ended up being covered by my listings. I had to use a combination of `tikz` and `atbegshi` to get what I wanted.

Comment: @Jubobs in those cases you can use the starred version `\newwatermark*` from `xwatermark`.

Comment: Another issue with `xwatermark` is that it relies on `fancyhdr`, so with `scrpage2` and very probably its successor `scrlayer-scrpage` you will get error messages.