# Switching between environments

Tags: environments, exam

I teach at the university and I write exams in Tex. 
I'd like to write an exam with a number of questions, where for each question I include either empty lines and empty figures with axes (for the actual exam - students to fill) OR the solution, including complete figures. For example:

```
Q. Illustrate what happens to the demand of housing when interest rates go down.

\begin{nosolution}
A FEW HORIZONTAL LINES
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{EmptyGraph_withAxes}
\end{figure}
\end{nosolution}

\begin{solution}
It will increase.... 
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{HousingDemand}
\end{figure}
\end{solution}
```

Then set a paramater at the beginning of the exam such as \printsolution, which says to print what is within the \begin{solution}...\end{solution}, and otherwise print what is within the \begin{nosolution} ... \end{nosolution}. 
I defined a solution and nosolution environment:

```
\newenvironment{solution}
{
\vspace{0.5cm}
\textbf{Solution.} \quad \itshape
}{}

\newenvironment{nosolution}
{
\hrulefill
\hrulefill
\hrulefill
}{}
```

Is there a way to switch between one and the other depending on an initial parameter like \printsolution? 
I have been trying the exam class (exam.cls) but it is not perfect for what I need to do because it cannot take floats in the solutions: I get a lost float message. I also checked the documentation which confirmed that floats are not supported because it uses frames. 
thanks,
Mario

Comment: If the problem are `floats` a possible solution is not using them. I include graphics in my exams with just `\includegraphics` (without `figure`) where I need them. `floats` mean this, graphics will appear where LaTeX considers. They are good for documents, but I don't think the same for short exams.

Comment: The comment package should allow you to switch one or other of the environments to be a "comment"

Comment: Besides David's comment, see also: [How to have upside down text in body?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161812)

Comment: You can make conditionals through the etoolbox package and implement an if-then-else branch.

Comment: Also see this answer where they hide custom environments: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15509/hide-custom-environment-content-based-on-boolean

Comment: Have you seen this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22269/comparing-packages-which-facilitate-typesetting-exercises-and-solutions-exercis/23232#23232 ?

Comment: http://www.ctan.org/topic/exam

Answer (score 2):

The `exsheets` package has ready made solutions for this. The following example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{exsheets}

% custom headings:
\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{myheading}{default}{
  runin           = true ,
  title-post-code = \space ,
  attach          = { main[l,vc]points[l,vc](\linewidth+\marginparsep,0pt) } ,
  join            = { main[r,vc]title[r,vc](0pt,0pt) }
}

% setup:
\SetupExSheets{
  headings       = myheading ,
  question/name  = Q. ,
  solution/name  = A. ,
  % solution/print = true
  solution/print = false
}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
  Illustrate what happens to the demand of housing when interest rates go down.
\end{question}

% if solutions are not printed:
\PrintSolutionsF{%
  \blank[width=4.8\linewidth,linespread=1.5]{}% 4.8 lines to write on
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=1]{EmptyGraph_withAxes}% demo picture
  \end{center}
}

% if solutions are pinted:
\begin{solution}
  It will increase\ldots
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=1]{HousingDemand}
  \end{center}
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

with `solution/print = false` and

[image]

with `solution/print = true`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `MWE` based on `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%\edef\printsolution{} % Uncomment to print solutions.

\newcommand{\nosolution}[1]{%
    \ifdefmacro{\printsolution}{}{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\solution}[1]{%
    \ifdefmacro{\printsolution}{#1}{}%
}{}

\begin{document}


\nosolution{
No solution.
}

\solution{
Solution.
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions and sorry if it took so long, but I was busy with teaching and then trying to play with all the proposed solutions. In the end I think this solution is the simplest and works great for me.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for the suggestions. In the end I took a bit from everyone and made my own customised commands. Hope this can be useful to others

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forloop,etoolbox}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Solutions
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Define an new command to switch between solution and nosolution with 
% empty lines instead
% Command showlines defines the number of lines. 

\newcommand{\nosolution}[1]{%
    \ifdefmacro{\printsolution}{}{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\solution}[1]{%
    \ifdefmacro{\printsolution}{\vskip0.1cm \noindent \textbf{Answer:} \textit{#1}}{}%
}

\newcounter{numlines}
\newcommand\showlines[1]{%
    \setcounter{numlines}{0}%
    \forloop{numlines}{0}{\value{numlines} < #1}{\vskip0.3cm \hrulefill}%
 }

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\edef\printsolution{} % Uncomment to print solutions.

\begin{document}

THIS IS THE QUESTION

\solution{THIS IS THE ANSWER. 
}
\nosolution{
\showlines{6}
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like below, setting `\showanswerstrue` or `\showanswersfalse` determines what is shown or what is hidden. It provides two ways to add an answer:

Use the `answer`/`noanswer` environment, which are defined with the `comment` package.
Or you can just enter the answer below the question and use `\onlyanswer` to hide parts. You probably want to add to this an optional argument to offer replacement text or a `\hrule`, this isn't built in right now. This can be used to hide parts of an answer for fill in questions or remove a plot from a graph. Note that if you have no plots in the graph you have to set up the `axis` by hand.

Finally there is a `\showlines{<n>}` command that draws `<n>` lines.

```
\documentclass{article}

%% Define the switch to control which is shown
\usepackage{comment,forloop}
\newif\ifshowanswers
\showanswersfalse   % Comment out one of these to show
%\showanswerstrue    % or hide the answers

%% Define the answer/noanswer environments and hide when necessary
\specialcomment{answer}{}{\vspace{2em}}     % Add some space between
\specialcomment{noanswer}{}{\vspace{2em}}   % the environments
\ifshowanswers% Hide either of the two environments defined above
  \excludecomment{noanswer}
\else
  \excludecomment{answer}
\fi

%% Define an environment to markup the questions
\newcounter{questionnumber}
\setcounter{questionnumber}{0}
\newenvironment{question}%
  {
    \stepcounter{questionnumber}
    \bf \arabic{questionnumber}.
  }
  {\par\vspace{1em}}

%% Some extra commands that might be helpful
\newcommand\onlyanswer[1]{\ifshowanswers{#1}\else{}\fi} % Discard contents if not needed
\newcommand\showlines[1]{%
    \newcounter{numlines}
    \forloop{numlines}{0}{\value{numlines} < #1}{\hrulefill\par}%
  }

%% Only necessary for the plot in the second example question
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
Introduction to exam

\begin{question}
Some question
\end{question}
\begin{answer}
The true answer to the question
\end{answer}
\begin{noanswer}
\showlines{3}
\end{noanswer}

\begin{question}
A second question with a plot to be filled in

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      xmin=0, xmax=10,
      ymin=0, ymax=100,
    ]
    \onlyanswer{\addplot[domain=0:10,no marks] {x^2};}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

**Update:** added some whitespace and a counter to number the questions