# Changebar: Different Colored Bars

Tags: changebar

I am using `\usepackage{changebar}` to indicate differences in two documents. At the moment, I use one color for all different kinds of changes. That does not make me happy. I would prefer to have at least two colors. One to show, where I added text. One to highlight passages, where I deleted text. Does anyone has a solution?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[color]{changebar}
\cbcolor{blue}

\begin{document}


Die Ergebnisse wurden hauptsächlich introspektiv erzielt.

\cbstart
Die Ergebnisse wurden hauptsächlich introspektiv erzielt.
\cbend

Die Ergebnisse wurden hauptsächlich introspektiv erzielt.

\end{document}
```

Comment: What you want is one of Peter Grill solutions in [Environments for visually setting text apart](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37246/1952)

Comment: @Ignasi: Thanks, I prefer the `changebox` option Harish Kumar provided. However, I am sure that I will use one of the options I found in Peter Grills compilation for other purposes soon. So again, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[xcolor]{changebar}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\deleted}[1]{%
  \cbcolor{red}
  \begin{changebar}
    #1
  \end{changebar}%
  }%

\newcommand{\added}[1]{%
  \cbcolor{green}
  \begin{changebar}
    #1
  \end{changebar}%
  }%

\setlength{\changebarsep}{2ex}
\begin{document}
  \deleted{\lipsum[1]}
  \lipsum[2]
  \added{\lipsum[3]}
\end{document}
```

[image]