# How best to differentiate questions and answers in a document without compromising on typesetting and readability?

Tags: macros, formatting, questionnaire

Preliminary note: I don't think this question is completely or even to a large extent subjective, as it seeks how to achieve objective utilitarian goals. Please read:

I am solving my QFT assignments in `LaTeX`. They're basically just a succession of questions and answers and I would be interested in your opinions on how to best make it clear to the reader if text belongs to a question or gives an answer.

In the past, I've written the whole question in italics, as in

```
\newcommand{\question}[1]{\itshape #1}
```

However, I never found this to be satisfactory, as it makes the questions harder to read and the entire page layout seem quite disrupted. Suggestions?

**Edit:** Manuel asked for a compilable example, so here you go. I stripped pretty much every bit of code not essential off of the following. Note that the answer to b) is hard to discern from the list of questions.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=25mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[range-units = single]{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-all,per-mode=fraction}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=0ex,label=\alph*)}
\setlist[itemize,1]{leftmargin=*}


\setlength{\parindent}{0ex}


\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
\newcommand{\der}{\operatorname{d\!}{}}
\newcommand{\spint}[1][x]{\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \! \der^3#1 \,}
\newcommand{\moint}{\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \! \frac{\der^3p}{\(\num{2}\pi\)^{\num{3}}} \,}
\newcommand{\vnabla}{\vec{\nabla}}
\renewcommand{\(}{\left(}
\renewcommand{\)}{\right)}
\renewcommand{\[}{\left[}
\renewcommand{\]}{\right]}
\let\phi\varphi



\begin{document}

\section{Canonical commutation relations}

Starting from the mode expansion of the Schrödinger fields
\begin{align}
&\phi\(\vec{x}\) = \moint \frac{\num{1}}{\sqrt{\num{2}\omega_{\vec{p}}}} \(a\(\vec{p}\)e^{i\vec{p}\vec{x}} + a^\dagger\(\vec{p}\)e^{-i\vec{p}\vec{x}}\), \\
\text{and} \quad &\pi\(\vec{x}\) = \moint (-i) \sqrt{\frac{\omega_{\vec{p}}}{\num{2}}} \(a\(\vec{p}\)e^{i\vec{p}\vec{x}} - a^\dagger\(\vec{p}\)e^{-i\vec{p}\vec{x}}\),
\end{align}
we’ll derive the canonical commutation relations for the modes $a\(\vec{p}\)$ and $a^\dagger\(\vec{p}\)$ using the steps below.
\begin{enumerate}
\item Perform a Fourier transformation to deduce the relation between the Fourier modes $\tilde{\phi}\(\vec{p}\)$, $\tilde{\pi}\(\vec{p}\)$, and the modes $a\(\vec{p}\)$ and $a^\dagger\(\vec{p}\)$.
\item Derive the commutation relations
\begin{equation}
\[\tilde{\phi}\(\vec{p}\),\tilde{\pi}\(\vec{q}\)\] = i \(\num{2}\pi\)^{\num{3}} \delta^{\(\num{3}\)}\(\vec{p} + \vec{q}\)
\end{equation}
from the canonical commutation relations for $\phi\(\vec{x}\)$ and $\pi\(\vec{x}\)$.

%%%%%% All text belongs to questions except for this block. %%%%%%
The canonical commutation relations for $\phi\(\vec{x}\)$ and $\pi\(\vec{x}\)$ states that $\[\phi\(\vec{x}\),\pi\(\vec{y}\)\] = i \delta^{\(\num{3}\)}\(\vec{x} - \vec{y}\)$. Therefore
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\[\tilde{\phi}\(\vec{p}\),\tilde{\pi}\(\vec{q}\)\]
&= \spint\spint[y] e^{-i\vec{p}\vec{x}} e^{-i\vec{p}\vec{y}} \underbrace{\[\phi\(\vec{x}\),\pi\(\vec{y}\)\]}_{i \delta^{\(\num{3}\)}\(\vec{x} - \vec{y}\)} \\
&= i \spint e^{-i\(\vec{p}+\vec{q}\)\vec{x}}
= i \(\num{2}\pi\)^{\num{3}} \delta^{\(\num{3}\)}\(\vec{p} + \vec{q}\)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\item Conclude that
\begin{equation}
\[a\(\vec{p}\),a^\dagger\(\vec{q}\)\] = \(\num{2}\pi\)^{\num{3}} \delta^{\(\num{3}\)}\(\vec{p} - \vec{q}\)
\quad \text{and} \quad
\[a\(\vec{p}\),a\(\vec{q}\)\] = \[a^\dagger\(\vec{p}\),a^\dagger\(\vec{q}\)\] = \num{0}.
\end{equation}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

**Update:** Two images in response to Peter Grill's solution.

[image]
[image]

Comment: A full compilable example with full example questions/answers so you we can have an idea of what you are up to would be great.

Comment: have a look into the `exsheets` documentary

Comment: You should typeset twocolumn questions, or balancing across two pages. `LaTeX` isn't proficient at this, but with proper effort you can get it done and I always had good experiences with it.

Comment: Perhaps one of the solutions at [Environments for visually setting text apart](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37245/environments-for-visually-setting-text-apart) would work for you. Personally I would use an `mdframed` box  with different background colors to distinguish the question and answer portion.

Comment: @MaxNoe This looks useful. It seems sometimes like there is a `LaTeX` package for every purpose. Then again there are other times... ah, let's not get into those.

Comment: Thanks for providing a MWE, but can you also mark which potions you consider `\question` and which you consider `\answer`?

Comment: @PeterGrill Sure.

Comment: @PeterGrill Isn't it a bad idea to redefine LaTeX's markup for beginning and ending maths mode? [I'm not picking on you! But I can only ping one person and I figure you will know....]

Comment: @cfr: Yeah, I think it is a bad idea -- I personally would not do it. But that isn't the thrust of this question -- perhaps would be as a new question though.

Comment: Since the questions seem to be short and the answers long, consider boxing the former and using plain text for the latter. Then page breaks in a box would be less likely, and possibly easily preventable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of using `mdframed` to highlight the answer portion:

[image]

### References:

- You might want to try some of the other alternatives in [Environments for visually setting text apart](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37245/environments-for-visually-setting-text-apart)

### Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=25mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[range-units = single]{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-all,per-mode=fraction}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=0ex,label=\alph*)}
\setlist[itemize,1]{leftmargin=*}


\setlength{\parindent}{0ex}


\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
\newcommand{\der}{\operatorname{d\!}{}}
\newcommand{\spint}[1][x]{\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \! \der^3#1 \,}
\newcommand{\moint}{\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \! \frac{\der^3p}{\(\num{2}\pi\)^{\num{3}}} \,}
\newcommand{\vnabla}{\vec{\nabla}}
\renewcommand{\(}{\left(}
\renewcommand{\)}{\right)}
\renewcommand{\[}{\left[}
\renewcommand{\]}{\right]}
\let\phi\varphi

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\newmdenv[%
    leftmargin=-5pt,
    rightmargin=-5pt, 
    innerleftmargin=5pt,
    innerrightmargin=5pt,
    backgroundcolor=brown!10,
]{Answer}%


\begin{document}

\section{Canonical commutation relations}

Starting from the mode expansion of the Schrödinger fields
\begin{align}
&\phi\(\vec{x}\) = \moint \frac{\num{1}}{\sqrt{\num{2}\omega_{\vec{p}}}} \(a\(\vec{p}\)e^{i\vec{p}\vec{x}} + a^\dagger\(\vec{p}\)e^{-i\vec{p}\vec{x}}\), \\
\text{and} \quad &\pi\(\vec{x}\) = \moint (-i) \sqrt{\frac{\omega_{\vec{p}}}{\num{2}}} \(a\(\vec{p}\)e^{i\vec{p}\vec{x}} - a^\dagger\(\vec{p}\)e^{-i\vec{p}\vec{x}}\),
\end{align}
we’ll derive the canonical commutation relations for the modes $a\(\vec{p}\)$ and $a^\dagger\(\vec{p}\)$ using the steps below.
\begin{enumerate}
\item Perform a Fourier transformation to deduce the relation between the Fourier modes $\tilde{\phi}\(\vec{p}\)$, $\tilde{\pi}\(\vec{p}\)$, and the modes $a\(\vec{p}\)$ and $a^\dagger\(\vec{p}\)$.
\item Derive the commutation relations
\begin{equation}
\[\tilde{\phi}\(\vec{p}\),\tilde{\pi}\(\vec{q}\)\] = i \(\num{2}\pi\)^{\num{3}} \delta^{\(\num{3}\)}\(\vec{p} + \vec{q}\)
\end{equation}
from the canonical commutation relations for $\phi\(\vec{x}\)$ and $\pi\(\vec{x}\)$.

\begin{Answer}
%%%%%% All text belongs to questions except for this block. %%%%%%
The canonical commutation relations for $\phi\(\vec{x}\)$ and $\pi\(\vec{x}\)$ states that $\[\phi\(\vec{x}\),\pi\(\vec{y}\)\] = i \delta^{\(\num{3}\)}\(\vec{x} - \vec{y}\)$. Therefore
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\[\tilde{\phi}\(\vec{p}\),\tilde{\pi}\(\vec{q}\)\]
&= \spint\spint[y] e^{-i\vec{p}\vec{x}} e^{-i\vec{p}\vec{y}} \underbrace{\[\phi\(\vec{x}\),\pi\(\vec{y}\)\]}_{i \delta^{\(\num{3}\)}\(\vec{x} - \vec{y}\)} \\
&= i \spint e^{-i\(\vec{p}+\vec{q}\)\vec{x}}
= i \(\num{2}\pi\)^{\num{3}} \delta^{\(\num{3}\)}\(\vec{p} + \vec{q}\)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{Answer}

\item Conclude that
\begin{equation}
\[a\(\vec{p}\),a^\dagger\(\vec{q}\)\] = \(\num{2}\pi\)^{\num{3}} \delta^{\(\num{3}\)}\(\vec{p} - \vec{q}\)
\quad \text{and} \quad
\[a\(\vec{p}\),a\(\vec{q}\)\] = \[a^\dagger\(\vec{p}\),a^\dagger\(\vec{q}\)\] = \num{0}.
\end{equation}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks really nice. I wondered what happens, when an answer spans multiple pages. Tested it and actually, that worked well. However, there are some issues with this approach. I changed my margins a little and now some math is sticking out of the box. This also happens when using `\smash` to prevent automatically resized brackets from allowing for `\underbrace`s. So perhaps even though it looks good, it is not a very robust solution. See the added image in my question for clarification.

Comment: @PacificOrion: That problem you mention with smash can happen with regular text as well -- the surrounding text somehow needs to know about that vertical space that was taken up. Try adding normal text afterwards and you'll notice that the vertical space is shorter than it is in normal display mode equations. Or make the `\smash`ed content several lines high; the problem will be even more obvious. IMHO that is not a problem with using this proposed solution, it is a problem in using `\smash` and requires that the surrounding text know about it.  If you post the full code I can try have a look.

Comment: You're right. In this particular instance, the following text had sufficient vertical distance for this to not show. After posting my comment, I fixed this problem by using a `\vphantom` after the brackets. I guess, the other issue is due to how `LaTeX` handles inline math expressions and probably requires manual tinkering. Or do you have any idea on a fix for that?

Comment: @PacificOrion: Without seeing exactly how you are changing the margins it is difficult to help you. I'd suggest you compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem, and post a new question.

Comment: Perhaps one more question: Can this be made to work with the `enumerate` environment so as to highlight the questions rather than the answers? When trying to include an item's counter in the highlighted box by placing `\item` within the `Answer` environment, LaTeX returns 'Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.'.

Comment: @PacificOrion: I think you need to look into the `resume` option from the `enumitem` package, but I think this really should be a separate question.