# mark text as checked for proofing

Tags: macros

When proofing a book, I would like some way to manage keeping track of which paragraphs, sections, etc have been checked. It should in no way effect the layout of the book.

e.g.,

```
\checked{This is a checked paragraph}
```

I figured I could make such a macro that might set the text color to black if it is checked but text color is red by default. This way it is easy to see visually in the pdf what has been checked.

Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: Does [Environments for visually setting text apart](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37245/4301) help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert on the package, but using [`todonotes`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/todonotes?lang=en) to put a note in the margin would seem like a reasonable approach.  The notes can be turned off by the package option 
`disable`.

I would use a simple macro like `\newcommand{\OK}{\todo[color=green!40]{Checked}}` so that the default notes to stand out and can be used for commenting as required.  You could then put `\OK{}` at the beginning or end of your paragraph (which seems better than wrapping the whole paragraph in a macro).

Answer (score 0):

The usual method for indicating proofing marks is to show what has been found requiring proofing, rather than what requires proofing.  So you draw a line in the margin corresponding to a change required, and mark the change in the line.

The method i use on http://www.os2fan2.com/pgloss/index.html , which is drawn from a single markup style, is to use paragraph styles like you have shown for all states of revision.  So there is a difference between the rewritten entries of the dictionary and the old ones.

You could use `\saa{}` and `sab{}` to indicate the change in state, and then proceed through the letters as you revise/update things.

Comment: The only problem I see is that I don't follow the usual method(as it is usually not very good).

Comment: The method i use is to change the paragraph environment from over from one style to another, like \checked{} and new{}  These are easy to find in a text editor (search or fold on the command).