# Brace and text in side margin

Tags: spacing, marginpar, braces

Within a text, I would like to emphasize one or two paragraphs by placing a curly brace in the left side margin, and next to it some short text vertically centred around the brace's centre.

The question [Adding a large brace next to a body of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/adding-a-large-brace-next-to-a-body-of-text) shows how to add braces in the main text, maybe that can help as a starting point? A slight modification of the accepted answer there is

```
\documentclass{report} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\noindent$\left\{
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\lipsum[2]
\end{minipage}
\right.$
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

But this has the drawbacks that

1. it spills into the right, not the left margin;
2. I cannot add text to the brace; and that
3. the line spacing before the braced paragraph is incorrect.

Maybe this can be modified, or a completely different approach should be used? But I wouldn't know which one.

Comment: Andrew Stacey's solution to that linked question is a more promising start of a solution.

Comment: I have been using the solution from [changbars to indicate location of conditional text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23007/changbars-to-indicate-location-of-conditional-text). This is not a curly brace but enough to make the paragraph stand out.  This has the added benefit that you can highlight portions of the text within the paragraph, and also useable within math mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a `\makebox` to define a new command with two arguments: the first one will contain the text for the brace, and the second one will contain the paragraph text; something along these lines:

```
\documentclass{report} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\BrText[2]{%
  \par\smallskip
   \noindent\makebox[\textwidth][r]{$\text{#1}\left\{
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    #2
    \end{minipage}
  \right.\nulldelimiterspace=0pt$}\par\smallskip
}    

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\BrText{Some text}{\lipsum[1]}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of guessing the dimension for the `\makebox` you can say `\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][r]{...}`; also you should set `\nulldelimiterspace=0pt` just before the closing `$`, otherwise a .5pt shift would apppear on the right.

Answer (score 2):

`\psbrace` from `pstricks-add` package can do this.  You need to position two nodes, and them connect them with the brace:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pstricks-add,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\makebox[0pt]{\makebox[1.5cm][l]{\pnode{A}}}
\lipsum[2]
\makebox[0pt]{\makebox[1.5cm][l]{\pnode{B}}}
\lipsum[3]
\psbrace[rot=180,ref=r, nodesepA=-2ex](A)(B){Text}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is it intentional that the brace isn't coextensive with the text?  i wouldn't have guessed it from the code.

Comment: You mean the end is below the paragraph?  I should put the second node slightly higher...

Comment: and perhaps the first node might be a bit higher as well -- at the top of the first line of that paragraph.  raising the height of both beginning and end by the same amount should do it.

Comment: Surely.  These adjustments can be made to taste...

Comment: For simplicity, let `P` be the paragraph covered by the brace. Am I right when I say that this is the only answer where `P` is not put inside a box or minipage? If yes, does this mean that this is the only solution where `P` can be broken in multiple pages?

Comment: Yes, I think so

Comment: Many thanks! And another thing, did you notice that the brace is slightly shifted down w.r.t. the paragraph? Do you know how remove this "offset"? Also, why did you put `\psbrace` after `\lipsum[3]` (i.e. the subsequent paragraph) instead of putting it immediatly after the second `\makebox` command?

Comment: Solved the vertical offset issue! In my case, I just replaced the two `\pnode` commands with `\pnode(0,0.5){A}` and `\pnode(0,0.5){B}` respectively, where the `0` value should always be `0`  and the `0.5` value worked for my particular case and could be different in other cases.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach that utilized the [`environ` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ). The two-step procedure boxes the contents (in `\savetextbox`) in order to get its height. Then it typesets the left brace in the margin, and then the box.

In the following minimal working example, a new environment `bracetext` is defined. It takes an optional argument which specifies the width of the text block (default is `\textwidth`). It is possible to modify this environment to take arguments (optional or mandatory) for the text to be displayed on the left-hand side as well.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{environ}% http://ctan.org/pkg/environ
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\newbox{\savetextbox}
\NewEnviron{bracetext}[1][\textwidth]{%
  \begin{lrbox}{\savetextbox}%
    \begin{minipage}{#1} \BODY \end{minipage}
  \end{lrbox}%
  \smallskip%
  \noindent\makebox[0pt][r]{$\left\{\rule{0pt}{\ht\savetextbox}\right.$}%
  \usebox{\savetextbox}\par
  \smallskip%
}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]
  \begin{bracetext}
    \lipsum[2]
  \end{bracetext}
  \lipsum[3]
\end{document}​
```

The [`lipsum` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) was used to provide dummy text *Lorem Ipsum...* style.

Note this one caveat of this approach is that the brace will not split across pages. If you want something that splits across pages, you should consider using [`mdframed`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed). However, it does not support bracing as you requested.

Comment: sadly, the baselines above and below the braced text aren't the same as elsewhere in the text, and the braced text doesn't have a paragraph indent (maybe that's intentional).

Comment: The latter was intentional as a consequence of inserting content in a `minipage` environment. Do you have a suggestion how to fix the former?

Comment: fixing the baseline above the `minipage` can be done by ending the previous line with a `\strut`.  actually, since you've used `\smallskip` here, four `\strut`s should do the job instead -- one on the previous line, one at the beginning of the `minipage` after a `\leavevmode`, one at the end of the `minipage`, and the last one after a `\leavevmode` (or `\indent`) at the beginning of the line beginning the next paragraph.  `\strut`s are your friend; they serve to maintain even baselines much more reliably than `\*skip`s.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution: The `schemata` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{schemata}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\hspace{-1cm}\schema{}{\lipsum[2]}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Answer (score 1):

This is a modification of the answer provided by [Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33998/60244), so that it works for two-column pages:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\BrLeftText[2]{%
  \par\smallskip
   \noindent\makebox[\columnwidth][r]{$\text{#1}\left\{
    \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
    #2
    \end{minipage}
  \right.\nulldelimiterspace=0pt$}\par\smallskip
}    
\newcommand\BrRightText[2]{%
  \par\smallskip
   \noindent\makebox[\columnwidth][l]{$\left.
    \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
    #2
    \end{minipage}
  \right\}$\text{#1}\nulldelimiterspace=0pt}\par\smallskip
} 
\newcommand\BrText[2]{
\if@firstcolumn \BrLeftText{#1}{#2} \else \BrRightText{#1}{#2} \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\BrText{left}{\lipsum[1]}
\newpage
\BrText{right}{\lipsum[1]}

\end{document}
```

[image]