# Braces spanning multiple tables (whole tables, not rows or pages)

Tags: tables, braces, marginnote, layout

I've got a bunch of tables arranged like so:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{minipage}[c][1\totalheight][t]{0.45\textwidth}%
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\ 
\hline 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
\hline 
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\par\end{center}
\caption{Table \#1}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\ 
\hline 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
\hline 
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
\hline 
\end{tabular}%
\par\end{center}
\caption{Table \#2}
\end{minipage}\hfill{}%
\begin{minipage}[c][1\totalheight][t]{0.45\textwidth}%

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\ 
\hline 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
\hline 
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\par\end{center}
\caption{Table \#3}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\ 
\hline 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
\hline 
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
\hline 
\end{tabular}%
\par\end{center}
\caption{Table \#4}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

And I'm trying to get braces to span multiple tables like so:

---

[image]

---

Or:

---

[image]

---

Or:

---

[image]

---

[Here's an example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33998/165801) of something I tried that uses the page margins. It works great for regular text, but not with objects like tables it seems:

```
\newcommand\BrText[2]{%
  \par\smallskip
   \noindent\makebox[\textwidth][r]{$\text{#1}\left\{
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    #2
    \end{minipage}
  \right.\nulldelimiterspace=0pt$}\par\smallskip
}
```

I tried working the problem a few other ways, but didn't think to hang on to non-working code at the time.
Anyway, I recall reading somewhere that it's possible, but not sure where. 
Any ideas how to do this would be much appreciated.

Comment: You really want the braces not to encompass the “Table 2” and “Table 4” captions?

Comment: @frougon I think either way is probably fine. Dealers choice :) Or both if you know both. Someone else might need the alternative

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
$\left\{
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.45\textwidth}%
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\ 
\hline 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
\hline 
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Table \#1}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\ 
\hline 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
\hline 
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
\hline 
\end{tabular}%
\end{center}
\caption{Table \#2}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.45\textwidth}%

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\ 
\hline 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
\hline 
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Table \#3}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\ 
\hline 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
\hline 
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
\hline 
\end{tabular}%
\end{center}
\caption{Table \#4}
\end{minipage}
\right\}$
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Beautiful, thanks. I actually tried that a bunch of times with minor variations and kept getting `Not in outer par mode`, `Undefined control sequence`, etc. Guess I didn't have it quite right.

Comment: `\par\end{center}`?

Comment: @egreg hmm yes copied from OP, I'll delete the `\par`

Comment: what's the problem

Comment: @tjt263 the `\par` does nothing useful (I simply deleted it) it might also be better to use `\centering` rather than `\begin{center}` here to avoid extra vertical space, but I left that.

Comment: I was wondering why `\par` was there. It must be left over from something else. I don't know what it does. I also never know whether to use `\centering` as opposed to `\begin{center}`. It's one of those questions that keep popping up when writing from scratch.

Comment: @tjt263 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23650/when-should-we-use-begincenter-instead-of-centering

Answer (score 4):

I provide two environments, `mybraceleft` and `mybraceright`, for conveniently bracing horizontal material. They both produce horizontal material (you can use them in the middle of a paragraph) of just the required size.

One notable property of my solution as compared to David's one is that it produces horizontal material that tightly wraps the `tabular` environments, or whatever you decide to use in their place (you don't have to guess the `0.45\textwidth` length). If you reduce the width of these elements, you'll see that my braces remain at the customizable distance `\myhsep` from the braced contents, which is not the case with David's solution (you'll have a larger gap between braces and contents because the `minipage` will have more whitespace inside, on the left and on the right of the tabular material).

A tricky part of the work with the requirements I set is to find the appropriate width for centering two `tabular` environments and two captions that go together. For this, I use the `eqparbox` package. This package relies on proper use of tags (for each tag, it finds the maximum width and allows you to use it as a normal length—this is extremely convenient, great package!). Watch for the tags in the source, they go by three (*one* for a `minipage` that tightly encloses *two* `tabular` environments and their associated captions). This process requires to compile the document at least twice.

## With no `table` environment

In this solution, the `table` environment isn't used, therefore nothing floats. This is mainly boxing work. `\captionof` from the `caption` package is used to produce the customary appearance of standard table captions.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hscale=0.65]{geometry} % enlarge margins a little bit for the example
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{caption}

\makeatletter

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\newlength{\myhsep} % Horizontal separation between brace and contents
\setlength{\myhsep}{0.7em}

\newenvironment{mybraceleft}{%
  \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
  }{%
  \end{lrbox}%
  $\m@th \left\{ \kern\myhsep \vcenter{\hbox{\usebox{\mybox}}} \right.$%
  \kern-\nulldelimiterspace
  \ignorespacesafterend
}

\newenvironment{mybraceright}{%
  \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
  }{%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \leavevmode
  \kern-\nulldelimiterspace
  $\m@th \left. \vcenter{\hbox{\usebox{\mybox}}} \kern\myhsep \right\}$%
  \ignorespacesafterend
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{mybraceleft}
  \begin{minipage}{\eqboxwidth{tag1}}
    \centering
    \begin{eqminipage}[c]{tag1}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|@{}}
      \hline
      a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
      \hline
      1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
      \hline
      a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{eqminipage}%
    \captionof{table}{Table \#1}
    \bigskip

    \begin{eqminipage}[c]{tag1}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|@{}}
      \hline
      a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
      \hline
      1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
      \hline
      a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{eqminipage}%
    \captionof{table}{Table \#2}
  \end{minipage}
\end{mybraceleft}% spaces would be ignored here anyway because of the
                 % \ignorespacesafterend we used
\hfill
\begin{mybraceleft}
  \begin{minipage}{\eqboxwidth{tag2}}
    \centering
    \begin{eqminipage}[c]{tag2}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|@{}}
      \hline
      a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
      \hline
      1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
      \hline
      a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{eqminipage}%
    \captionof{table}{Table \#3}
    \bigskip

    \begin{eqminipage}[c]{tag2}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|@{}}
      \hline
      a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
      \hline
      1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
      \hline
      a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{eqminipage}%
    \captionof{table}{Table \#4}
  \end{minipage}
\end{mybraceleft}

\vspace{2cm}
\noindent
\begin{mybraceleft}
  \begin{minipage}{\eqboxwidth{tag3}}
    \centering
    \begin{eqminipage}[c]{tag3}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|@{}}
      \hline
      a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
      \hline
      1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
      \hline
      a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{eqminipage}%
    \captionof{table}{Table \#5}
    \bigskip

    \begin{eqminipage}[c]{tag3}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|@{}}
      \hline
      a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
      \hline
      1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
      \hline
      a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{eqminipage}%
    \captionof{table}{Table \#6}
  \end{minipage}
\end{mybraceleft}% spaces would be ignored here anyway because of the
                 % \ignorespacesafterend we used
\hfill
\begin{mybraceright}
  \begin{minipage}{\eqboxwidth{tag4}}
    \centering
    \begin{eqminipage}[c]{tag4}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|@{}}
      \hline
      a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
      \hline
      1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
      \hline
      a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{eqminipage}%
    \captionof{table}{Table \#7}
    \bigskip

    \begin{eqminipage}[c]{tag4}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|@{}}
      \hline
      a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
      \hline
      1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
      \hline
      a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{eqminipage}%
    \captionof{table}{Table \#8}
  \end{minipage}
\end{mybraceright}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

## Wrapping braced material inside tables

This is close to the previous example, the only difference is that we allow two big chunks (each containing four `tabular` environments) to float. Thus, we use the `table` environment and can use `\caption` instead of `\captionof`. No need for the `caption` package in this case. This is similar to what David did, except for the input syntax (`mybraceleft` and `mybraceright` here) and horizontal spacing around the braces: my braces stay at a constant, customizable distance from the braced material (`\myhsep`).

As already mentioned, this requires two compilation runs to allow `eqparbox` to do its work.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hscale=0.65]{geometry} % enlarge margins a little bit for the example
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\makeatletter

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\newlength{\myhsep} % Horizontal separation between brace and contents
\setlength{\myhsep}{0.7em}

\newenvironment{mybraceleft}{%
  \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
  }{%
  \end{lrbox}%
  $\m@th \left\{ \kern\myhsep \vcenter{\hbox{\usebox{\mybox}}} \right.$%
  \kern-\nulldelimiterspace
  \ignorespacesafterend
}

\newenvironment{mybraceright}{%
  \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
  }{%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \leavevmode
  \kern-\nulldelimiterspace
  $\m@th \left. \vcenter{\hbox{\usebox{\mybox}}} \kern\myhsep \right\}$%
  \ignorespacesafterend
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{mybraceleft}
  \begin{minipage}{\eqboxwidth{tag1}}
    \centering
    \begin{eqminipage}[c]{tag1}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|@{}}
      \hline
      a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
      \hline
      1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
      \hline
      a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{eqminipage}%
    \caption{Table \#1}
    \bigskip

    \begin{eqminipage}[c]{tag1}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|@{}}
      \hline
      a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
      \hline
      1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
      \hline
      a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{eqminipage}%
    \caption{Table \#2}
  \end{minipage}
\end{mybraceleft}% spaces would be ignored here anyway because of the
                 % \ignorespacesafterend we used
\hfill
\begin{mybraceleft}
  \begin{minipage}{\eqboxwidth{tag2}}
    \centering
    \begin{eqminipage}[c]{tag2}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|@{}}
      \hline
      a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
      \hline
      1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
      \hline
      a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{eqminipage}%
    \caption{Table \#3}
    \bigskip

    \begin{eqminipage}[c]{tag2}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|@{}}
      \hline
      a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
      \hline
      1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
      \hline
      a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{eqminipage}%
    \caption{Table \#4}
  \end{minipage}
\end{mybraceleft}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{mybraceleft}
  \begin{minipage}{\eqboxwidth{tag3}}
    \centering
    \begin{eqminipage}[c]{tag3}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|@{}}
      \hline
      a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
      \hline
      1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
      \hline
      a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{eqminipage}%
    \caption{Table \#5}
    \bigskip

    \begin{eqminipage}[c]{tag3}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|@{}}
      \hline
      a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
      \hline
      1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
      \hline
      a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{eqminipage}%
    \caption{Table \#6}
  \end{minipage}
\end{mybraceleft}% spaces would be ignored here anyway because of the
                 % \ignorespacesafterend we used
\hfill
\begin{mybraceright}
  \begin{minipage}{\eqboxwidth{tag4}}
    \centering
    \begin{eqminipage}[c]{tag4}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|@{}}
      \hline
      a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
      \hline
      1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
      \hline
      a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{eqminipage}%
    \caption{Table \#7}
    \bigskip

    \begin{eqminipage}[c]{tag4}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|@{}}
      \hline
      a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
      \hline
      1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
      \hline
      a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{eqminipage}%
    \caption{Table \#8}
  \end{minipage}
\end{mybraceright}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I am wondering if you could solve [this problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/482518/121799).

Comment: @user121799 Well, well, well... I love parsing tasks (cf. link title), unfortunately the question you linked to is about 3D in Ti*k*Z and I haven't explored this field yet. I'm not even sure I understand what is missing from the already-accepted answer. I guess it has to do with the internal representation of 3D points in Ti*k*Z and how they undergo transformations, but I'm afraid I'm still too ignorant in these areas to contribute. :-/

Comment: OK, well. Anyway, maybe you can keep this question in the back of your mind if you ever go 3d. It would be great if one could somehow associate *three* instead of two coordinates to a symbolic coordinate, and if then veclen would spit out the distance between those. And so on. All my attempts to make 3d operations simpler struggled with that obstacle.

Comment: Thanks. What benefit does this provide that the much simpler alternative doesn't?

Comment: I explained the in the answer. 1) The `mybraceleft` and `mybraceright` environments allow to very simply brace arbitrary horizontal material (no need to switch to math mode and manually do the work). 2) You don't have to guess a suitable `minipage` width. 3) The horizontal space next to braces doesn't depend on the braced contents and is customizable (`\myhlen`). Try with narrower tables and you'll see. 4) The braced contents is tightly boxed (try wrapping it with `\frame` or adding stuff to its right after narrowing the tables). But you are not forced to use it!

Comment: I think I may have just noticed what you're talking about. I have 12 tables on a page.  So this x3. And there is a small gap between the outer brace on the right-hand side, and the margin. So it's pushed over to keep it centered, but it's still offset from the margin by a little bit (but only on the right hand side - the left hand side is hard up against the left margin). Is that what you mean?

Comment: It is hard to tell from your description. But you can understand my main point very easily. Just take David's code and keep only two columns per table. Then you'll see what I mean about consistent (and customizable) horizontal spacing between braces and braced contents.

Comment: No problem, I haven't implemented it your way yet, but I will come back around to it. Sorry, Davids suggestion was too easy, I had to give it to him despite your significant efforts. I hope it doesn't discourage you in the future. We appreciate you.