# Left bar in the margin of an environment with figures/tables

Tags: environments, margins

I am writing a document with theorems and proofs. Since, some reader may not be interested by the proofs I want to highlight them so they can be skipped easily.

The best idea I came up with is to put a bar in the left margin of the proof (if you have any better ideas I am interested).

The problem is that some proofs may take more than one page and contain figures and/or tables. Currently I found a solution in a previous post which uses the package framed and the command \leftbar. It works for several pages but not for figures and tables.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}

\renewenvironment{leftbar}[1][\hsize]
{%
    \def\FrameCommand
    {%
        {\color{black}\vrule width 0.5pt}%
        \hspace{0pt}%must no space.
        \fboxsep=\FrameSep\colorbox{white}%
    }%
    \MakeFramed{\hsize#1\advance\hsize-\width\FrameRestore}%
}
{\endMakeFramed}

 \newenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\leftbar\begin{trivlist}\item[\hskip\labelsep {\bfseries#1}]}{\end{trivlist}\endleftbar}

\def\fact{It is  practically a big lie  that LaTeX makes  you focus on
  the content without bothering about the layout.}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
  \fact
\end{proof} % Works

%\begin{proof}
%  \fact
%  \begin{figure}
%    \centering My figure
%    \caption{Test figure}
%  \end{figure}
%\end{proof} % Does not works

\end{document}
```

I don't really understand how environments work. Do you know if it's possible to make this work for proofs which include tables or figures?

(if you know why the bar starts one line before the proof and finish one line after I am also interested but it is not my main concern)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The main problem is that `figure` is a floating environment, so may well be moved out of the area used by the proof.  By the way, you want to try the `mdframed` package instead, but that won't solve the floating problem.

Comment: To clarify, for me it is not a problem if the figure does not have the bar in the left margin.

However, I am not sure it will help...

Comment: Related Questions: [1. Changbars to indicate location of conditional text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23007/changbars-to-indicate-location-of-conditional-text), and [2. Environments for visually setting text apart](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37245/environments-for-visually-setting-text-apart). You could perhaps adapt the solution from there. I'd recommend you consider using an `mdframed` environment for the proofs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place the `proof` inside the `figure` environment, or else the "fact" may end up in a different location than the figure.

EDITED to allow for multi-figures and page breaks in proofs (by using the `\captionof{figure}{}` approach).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewenvironment{leftbar}[1][\hsize]
{%
    \def\FrameCommand
    {%
        {\color{black}\vrule width 0.5pt}%
        \hspace{0pt}%must no space.
        \fboxsep=\FrameSep\colorbox{white}%
    }%
    \MakeFramed{\hsize#1\advance\hsize-\width\FrameRestore}%
}
{\endMakeFramed}

 \newenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\leftbar\begin{trivlist}\item[\hskip\labelsep {\bfseries#1}]}{\end{trivlist}\endleftbar}

\def\fact{It is  practically a big lie  that LaTeX makes  you focus on
  the content without bothering about the layout.}
\def\gappar{\vspace{1em}\par}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
  \fact
\end{proof} % Works

\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{proof}
  \fact\gappar
   \centering\fbox{My figure}
    \caption{Test figure}
\end{proof} % Now it works
\end{figure}

\begin{proof}
  \fact\gappar
    {\centering\fbox{My figure 1}
    \captionof{figure}{Test figure 1}\gappar}
   \lipsum[4]\gappar
    {\centering\fbox{My figure 2}
    \captionof{figure}{Test figure 2}\gappar}
    QED
\end{proof} % Now it works
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am afraid it will just work for one figure and if the proof is smaller than one page.

Comment: @Zach  The `figure` environment in general will only work for a single page.  If you wanted a faux environment, you could load the `caption` package, use the `\includegraphics` *without* the `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}` wrapper, and use `\captionof{figure}{my caption}` to underlay the caption.  If you can't follow what I'm saying, say so, and I will revise my answer to show it.

Comment: @Zach Please see my edit.

Comment: Indeed, using captionof and replacing all the figure and table environments in my proof by center environments worked.

It may not be the most elegant solution but currently that suits me perfectly.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

I have another solution where the word "Proof" is placed *before* the bar, and the bar can break across pages. It essentially uses the `ntheorem` and `framed` packages. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[svgnames, x11names]{xcolor}
%\usepackage[showframe,nomarginpar]{geometry}%
%\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[framed]{ntheorem}

\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape\small}
\theoremheaderfont{\color{IndianRed3}\sffamily\bfseries}%
\newlength{\FrameIndent}
\settowidth{\FrameIndent}{Proof\hspace{2\fboxsep}}%
\def\FrameCommand{%
\hspace*{\FrameIndent}\textcolor{IndianRed3}{\vrule width 0.6pt}\hspace{\fboxsep}
}%

\newframedtheorem{proof}{\llap{Proof\hspace{4\fboxsep}}\hspace{-\parindent}}%%{Proof}%

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{proof}
  \lipsum[4-6]
\end{proof} %

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]