# How should I add visual indications of excerpted sections?

Tags: formatting, highlighting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Putting a bar in the margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10606/putting-a-bar-in-the-margin)
>   [How to make continuous (but breakable) vertical rule along left side of paragraph?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35815/how-to-make-continuous-but-breakable-vertical-rule-along-left-side-of-paragrap)

I'm planning on including large excerpts of publications in my thesis.  I would like to highlight these in some way that would make visually clear the distinction between these sections and my newly written thesis text.  These excerpts are multi-page fully formatted sections replete with typeset math and figures.  My thesis text references equations and figures in these excerpts and both share the same bibliography.

What I'd like to do is to place a vertical line in the margin beside these excerpts.  Is there any way to write an environment to do that in latex?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35815/how-to-make-continuous-but-breakable-vertical-rule-along-left-side-of-paragrap/ While the question was intended for plain TeX, there are a couple of LaTeX solutions as well, the easiest seemingly Herberts suggestion (`leftbar` environment from `framed` package).

Comment: will you be typesetting the excerpts, or will they be included using (for example) `includegraphics` or `pdfpages`?

Comment: I will be typesetting them.  I was concerned that if I tried pdfpages I wouldn't be able to reference the equation and figure numbers.