# Text markers on the margin

Tags: margins

Sometimes, I want to mark a section of my manuscript for later inspection. So far I have been using a different color, but I really do not like it. I was wondering if I can draw a black strip on the margin. Ideally, it should work across pages and with equations. I believe it should be possible to do since draft mode already does something similar. But I do not know where to start.

MWE for testing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newenvironment{marked}{}{}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{marked}
  \lipsum[5]
  \[ x = y\]
  \lipsum[6]
\end{marked}
\end{document}
```

Desired output:

[image: Desired output]

Comment: You have the `leftbar` environment from the `framed` package.

Comment: Is it the same question of this link? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175755/vertical-line-next-to-a-block-with-no-margins

Comment: @Sebastiano, yes! My search did not come up with that answer for some reason.