# How can I mark and label certain regions in the margin with ConTeXt?

Tags: margins, context

I write a document that discusses syntactic differences between two languages (let's say, TeX and Markdown). Going through various topics, the text talks some time about one language and then about the other language.

What I want to do is to place marks in the margin to show which regions discuss TeX and which discuss Markdown. For example:

```
Here are some paragraphs   \
discussing features        | TeX
                           |
of TeX.                    /

And the text starting here \
                           | Markdown
discusses Markdown         /
```

Since I have quite some region pairs like this, I would like to generate them with environment, like so:

```
\starttexdiscussion
Here are some paragraphs discussing features

of TeX.
\stoptexdiscussion

\startmarkdowndiscussion
And the text starting here

discusses Markdown
\stopmarkdowndiscussion
```

Is it possible to define environments that do that for me? How would I adjust position and length of the margin content to match the main content? How could I handle page breaks?

Comment: Does this have to break across pages?

Comment: Well it would be great if it would automatically split in two when it encounters a page break, but primarily I want to know how to generally align margin content with main content.

Comment: Conceptually, this should be in the direction of what you want: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436250/colored-bar-next-to-text-over-multiple-pages/436255#436255

Comment: This looks quite nice. Can you explain a bit how it works, specifically `nofmultipars`? I did a quick search in the MetaFun manual, but didn't find anything.

Comment: Good question.  I just read the source code of [`anch-bck.mkvi`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/beta/tex/context/base/mkiv/anch-bck.mkvi) and [`mp-abck.mpiv`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/beta/metapost/context/base/mpiv/mp-abck.mpiv).  Usually I learn about the existence of these things by reading the mailing list.

Comment: Ah, `nofmultipars` apparently means *number of multipars*, that makes sense. I assume `multipars` and this number is set by using the graphic as text background. It seems to be a list of content split by page break.

Comment: Ah, that was the question.  Yes, `nofmultipars` is the number of `multipars` where each `multipar` is some region where ConTeXt decides to spit the input (page breaks, column breaks, around floats).

Comment: Getting a curly brace into the `textbackground` is relatively easy but I have no idea how to get changeable text in there, because `textbackground` are handled in a second pass.  http://dpaste.com/836NS4UQG (expires in 10 days)

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks a lot, I simply wrapped that in a macro to have different text (see the answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution based on Henri Menke's comments that does exactly what is described, including splitting the braces when page breaks are encountered.

```
\def\definebraceddiscussion#1[#2]#3[#4]{
  \startuseMPgraphic{#2frame}
    begingroup;
        numeric n ;
        pair lr, ur ;
        picture p ;
        for i=1 upto nofmultipars :
            lr := lrcorner multipars[i] ;
            ur := urcorner multipars[i] ;
            n := arclength(lr -- ur) / 2 ;
            p := textext.rt("$\left.\vrule height " & decimal n & "bp width 0pt depth 0pt\right\}$") ;
            draw p shifted (.5[lr,ur] + (EmWidth,0));
            label.rt("#4", .5[lr,ur] shifted (.75cm, 0)) ;
        endfor ;
    endgroup;
  \stopuseMPgraphic
  \definetextbackground[#2Frame]
    [mp=#2frame, location=paragraph]
  \definestartstop[#2discussion]
    [before={\starttextbackground[#2Frame]},
     after={\stoptextbackground[#2Frame]}]
}

\definebraceddiscussion[tex][TeX]
\definebraceddiscussion[markdown][Markdown]

\starttext

\starttexdiscussion

  \input knuth

  \input tufte

\stoptexdiscussion

\startmarkdowndiscussion

  \input ward

  \input zapf

\stopmarkdowndiscussion

\stoptext
```

Comment: There is a fancy brace (I think copied from the metafont code for computer modern font) available if you load `\useMPlibrary[fen]`. It can be used as:             `fill BasicBraceSymbol(180) ysized (ypart ur - ypart lr) shifted ( 0.5[lr,ur] ) ;`. It looks better at small sizes (5-8 lines) but looks really weird once you go above a certain number of lines (10 to 15 or so).