# Why does the changebar package not work in revtex

Tags: tcolorbox, revtex, changebar

I am writing a response letter in LaTeX using `\documentclass` `revtex4-2`. I also include the `changebar` package as suggested in [Vertical line next to a block](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175755/vertical-line-next-to-a-block-with-no-margins), trying to highlight the text by the bar on the side. Here are the details:

```
\documentclass[aps,prl,preprint,superscriptaddress,letterpaper]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[leftbars, color]{changebar}
\cbcolor{red}
```

However, when I want to highlight a paragraph using `cbstart` and `cbend`, it does not work at all. For example:

```
\cbstart
In particle theory, the skyrmion is a topologically stable field configuration 
of a certain class of non-linear sigma models
\cbend
```

However, when I change to the ordinary `\documentclass`, it works properly:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
```

So the LaTeX code should be right. I guess it may attribute to the  `revtex4-2` can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome. As always on this site, please provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is.

Comment: both changebar and revtex4-2 patch the output routine and debugging why their patches clash is rather hard. It will imho be easier to implement such a bar with tcolorbox.

Answer (score 1):

When using the `tcolorbox` package to put the left bar `revtex4-2` doesn't complain.

[image: a]

Environment  `MarkNote`

```
\begin{MarkNote}{<bar color>}{<bar indent>}
```

```
\documentclass[aps,prl,preprint,superscriptaddress,letterpaper]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}% make the vertical rule

\newtcolorbox{MarkNote}[2]{%
    breakable,
    outer arc=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    colback=white,
    leftrule=3pt, % rule width
    rightrule=0pt,
    toprule=0pt,
    top=0pt,
    right=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    bottomrule=0pt,
    colframe=#1,
    enlarge left by=#2,
    width=\linewidth-#2,    
}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\kant[1]

\begin{MarkNote}{red}{3em}
In particle theory, the skyrmion is a topologically stable field configuration 
of a certain class of non-linear sigma models.
\end{MarkNote}  

\kant[2]

\end{document}
```