# How to draw punch holes in the margins?

Tags: margins, texlive

The objective is to draw circles in the place where the punch holes will be once the PDF is printed in a physical sheet of paper (If it matters, consider a two-hole punch.). [Some sources](https://yourbusiness.azcentral.com/print-word-leave-room-hole-punch-3930.html) say the holes are usually 0.5 in (1.27 cm) away from the edge of the paper. The closest thing I found was an answer that talks about the [`pdfcomment` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10625/134742). I have not tried that, but I think that it might be overkill and that there should be a simpler way.

Written as a more general question: How can you draw/write in the margins?

Software: texlive 2018, macOS.

Comment: The `background` package might be helpful.

Comment: You can draw anywhere (including off the page!) so long as you tell LaTeX to ignore the size of the thing you are drawing - e..g put it in a box of zero size and let it overflow. You also need a "fixed" known position on every page to use as a datum point. That's basically how the answer suggesting `eso-pic` works.

Comment: `pdfcomment` looks like the wrong tool, because the comments are associated with the *content* of the document, which might be anywhere on the page. You want your circles in a *fixed* position on every page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of possibilities. A simple one is with eso-pic:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\AtPageUpperLeft{%
 \put(\LenToUnit{1cm},\LenToUnit{-10cm}){\LARGE$\circ$}}}
\begin{document}
blblbl

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I added an image if you dont' mind.

Comment: Thanks Ulrike and thank you Sigur for adding an image! Any way I can achieve this without using packages?